# PowerShell Get-AzureADUser cmdlet does unwanted String conversion

Tags: string, powershell, datetime, azure-active-directory, string-conversion

I am storing timestamps in Azure AD User Extension Properties for a custom application.
My extension property is a String data type (available data types are String and Binary).
I am using -format o to get my timestamp string:

```
[String]$thisTimestamp = (Get-Date -f o)
```

This gives me a string containing my timestamp formatted as follows:

`2017-11-17T18:26:13.5537900+00:00`

When I store this string value in my AzureAD Extension Property it appears to go through a String-DateTime-String conversion which results in the default date formatting as follows:

```
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId -ExtensionName $thisExtensionID -ExtensionValue $thisTimestamp
(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId).get_item($thisExtensionID)
```

Returns: `17/11/2017 18:26:13`

Looking at the stored value in the MS Graph Explorer, it is stored correctly as a timestamp. However, when I Get the value, either with Get-AzureADUserExtension or with Get-AzureADUser and examine the properties, the stored value is always returned as a string, with the format modified:

```
((Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId).extensionproperty).$thisExtensionID
```

Returns:
`17/11/2017 18:26:13`

I have a workaround - adding a trailing space to my timestamp. This is correctly stored as a string, and converts back to a DateTime correctly.

```
[String]$thisTimestamp = (Get-Date -f o) + " "
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId -ExtensionName $thisExtensionID -ExtensionValue $thisTimestamp
(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId).get_item($thisExtensionID)
```

Returns: `2017-11-17T18:26:13.5537900+00:00` (with a trailing space)

```
$testDateTime = Get-Date (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $aadUser.ObjectId).get_item($thisExtensionID)
```

Correctly creates a DateTime object and returns:
`17 November 2017 18:26:13`

It seems wrong to me that the Get-AzureADUser cmdlet and the Get-AzureADUserExtension (which I assume is based on Get-AzureADUser) seem to be interfering with the string as it is retrieved. Is this a bug, or am I doing something stoopid?

Comment: Check the value of the extension property via the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to see what it's being stored as. Go to that page, sign in, change the second drop dowm from 1.0 to beta and query the user with the extension property.

Comment: Excellent - thank you. This will help me work out what's going on.
The timestamp is being correctly stored as a string.

Comment: It looks like both Get-AzureADUserExtension and a straightforward Get-AzureADUser are incorrectly returning the string converted from date (21/11/2017 17:15:08) rather than the actual string value saved in the property (2017-11-21T17:15:08.4228131+00:00).